# iOS web application configuration meta tags not working

Tags: php, html, ios, meta-tags

I'm developing a website locally on a MAMP stack. My header is wrapped in a php template and included on every webpage. The problem is: none of the [meta tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) needed to configure a website as an iOS standalone web application are working. I've used `window.navigator.standalone` to alert the status of the standalone (in case it was executing but not rendering) but it's always false.

Things I've tried: 
1. removing the php templates and including the header html directly.
2 reordering the meta tags (in case the parsing order was important).

Neither of them worked. I appreciate any considerations or help you can offer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you have your HTML5 doctype defined properly (as window.navigator.standalone is an HTML5 feature)? That should be:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Next, what browser(s) are you using to test? Per the following article, you need to test for both the existence of the window.navigator.standalone property and the "truthiness" of it:

```
if ( ("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone ){

   // .... code here ....
}
```

[Detecting iPhone's App Mode (Full Screen Mode) for Web Applications](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-detecting-iphone-s-app-mode-full-screen-mode-for-web-applications.htm)

Comment: @leanna: Yes, I have declared my HTML5 doctype properly. Also, I'm testing in iOS 8.1. I've updated my js test with the updated code you've provided but, unfortunately, the outcome is still the same.

Comment: Just an update. I'm not sure why or how, but restarting my iPhone seems to have fixed whatever problem was causing the issue. Thank you for your help.